# NDepend: how to export the result from a query

Tags: linq, ndepend, cqlinq

I've got a CQLinq query which returns a list of methods and a list of members for each of them. Exporting the query result will only show the number of elements. I thought about using a Linq `Aggregate( (a,b) => a + ',' + b)`. Is there a better solution?

```
let type = Application.Types.WithFullName("WPF.ViewModels.CouponViewModel").Single()
let dicoFields  =  type.Fields
   .ToDictionary(f => f, f => f.MethodsUsingMe.Where(m => m.ParentType == f.ParentType))
let dicoMethods = type.Methods
   .ToDictionary(m => m, m => m.MembersUsed.Where(f => f.ParentType == m.ParentType))

// The partition algorithm on both dicos here

//from pair in dicoFields 
//orderby   pair.Value.Count() descending
//select new { pair.Key, pair.Value } 

from pair in dicoMethods 
orderby   pair.Value.Count() descending
select new { pair.Key, pair.Value}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can rewrite your query this way:

```
let type = Application.Types.WithFullName("WPF.ViewModels.CouponViewModel").Single()
let dicoMembers  =  type.ChildMembers
   .ToDictionary(x => x, x => 
  x.IsField ? x.AsField.MethodsUsingMe.Where(m => m.ParentType == x.ParentType):
              x.AsMethod.MembersUsed.Where(f => f.ParentType == x.ParentType))

from pair in dicoMembers
orderby   pair.Value.Count() descending
select new { 
 pair.Key, 
 str = pair.Value.Any() ?
    pair.Value.Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate( (a,b) => a + " ; " + b) :
    "empty"
}
```

- Both methods and fields are taken account
- Methods using fields and members used by methods are aggregated in a string

Then you can export the result:

[image: Exporting NDepend query result]